# I've been spending time [identifying] bad tags and this one qualifies

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

So, apparently, there's an [identifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/identifying) tag. 31 questions, so it qualifies for abbreviated burnination.

There's no tag Wiki or usage guidance, and it's unclear what this tag is even supposed to mean in the first place. Identifying *what*, exactly?

A lot of these are "how do I identify *x*" type questions, where *x* could be just about anything. For example,

- [Is this a good way to identify the type of a javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775758/is-this-a-good-way-to-identify-the-type-of-a-javascript-object)
- [Identifying points in a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106237/identifying-points-in-a-curve)
- [need assisrance Identifying the coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653137/need-assisrance-identifying-the-coding) - this one's rather low quality
- [Lex: C keyword rules not identifying correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895598/lex-c-keyword-rules-not-identifying-correctly)

So, this tag could really be about almost anything - the only thing they have in common is that the OP is trying to identify *something*.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** No, this is a Meta tag.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** No, it's too ambiguous.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** It's not even a topic, so this doesn't apply.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** No, I gave several examples above of completely different contexts.

This tag isn't attracting a lot of garbage, so it's mostly just a retagging effort. All of the questions can do without it in my opinion. Is it ok to do the retagging?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I fully support this. It seems like most of the questions are all in different contexts. There are some good questions, some bad, and some right in the middle. Overall, it doesn't seem to contribute much to the site and I think it deserves burnination.

Comment: I agree - it seems like a lot of them are "how can I identify `x`" type questions where `x` could be almost anything.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yes, and I think just because of its ambiguity in all cases, that there could never be a clear tag wiki established for it that covers all bases.